# iOS 8 Today extensionContext.openUrl not working

Tags: ios, xamarin, deep-linking, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

From the today extension, I use the following code to open a url in the main app. It works totally fine in iOS 9+, but in iOS 8 it never hits the openUrl method in AppDelegate but simply launches the app.

```
extensionContext.OpenUrl (url, (bool success) => { } );
```

How can I achieve a similar deep linking behavior in iOS 8? I've also tried `SharedApplication.OpenUrl` which worked in iOS 9+ but not in iOS 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 8, you have to implement [the version of openURL that was deprecated in iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:):

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    NSArray *pathComponents = [url pathComponents];
    NSString *action = url.host;
    // handle URL
}
```